# Entitlements file was modified during the build, which is not supported

Tags: ios, xcode

I'm getting following error during release build:

> error: Entitlements file "projectname.entitlements" was modified during the build, which is not supported. You can disable this error by setting 'CODE_SIGN_ALLOW_ENTITLEMENTS_MODIFICATION' to 'YES', however this may cause the built product's code signature or provisioning profile to contain incorrect entitlements.

I can't find `CODE_SIGN_ALLOW_ENTITLEMENTS_MODIFICATION` on Google or Apple documentation, any ideas where should I use it?

Answer (score 207, accepted):

I fixed this with `Product > Clean Build Folder`.

Comment: This worked for me when I hit the error after adding a new entitlement to my app

Comment: this should be the accepted answer. setting CODE_SIGN_ALLOW_ENTITLEMENTS_MODIFICATION to yes may cause bugs in the future

Comment: This should be the correct answer as @LouisCouture stated

Answer (score 37):

Ran into the same issue. You can set `CODE_SIGN_ALLOW_ENTITLEMENTS_MODIFICATION` as a User-Defined setting in Build Setting.

- In Xcode click on your project target and click Build Settings.
- Click the "+" underneath Build Settings and then "Add User-Defined Setting"
- Set `CODE_SIGN_ALLOW_ENTITLEMENTS_MODIFICATION` to `YES` for debug and release (or whatever schemes you like)

[image: Screenshot of where to go in Xcode]

Comment: While this may make the error to go away, it is probably NOT what you really want. Apple warns you that this setting is not safe: *...this may cause the built product's code signature or provisioning profile to contain incorrect entitlements.*

Answer (score 21):

Before you start modifying the build settings you can also try deleting the Derived data in your install or build directory.

If the project cache is found in the standard location below you can do an Xcode clean and it will get rid of this data.

```
/Users/your_user_name/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Path_To_Project/
```

If you defined your own install or build paths then go to that specific directory and delete that cache. Xcode should provide you the path if that error happens.

Comment: This did the trick for me. I was a bit nervous about setting the flag to allow entitlements modification, because my app didn't require that, and it seems to be a bit "heavy" approach. Weird error anyway.

Answer (score 2):

If `Clean Build Folder` doesn't help, make sure you don't have the same workspace/project opened in multiple `Windows` or `Window Tabs`!

(Xcode allows to open multiple tabs via `File -> New -> Window Tab`)

Comment: Cleaning did nothing, but closing all my tabs fixed it. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I've actually run into this EXACT same Compile-time error when I did the following in GitHub Client:

```
 **Discarded changes in my Git Repo for an entitlement file.**
```

[image]

It's imperative like suggested above, "Clean Build Folder" or add USER defined key `CODE_SIGN_ALLOW_ENTITLEMENTS_MODIFICATION` to YES.

I know it's been answered above but I wanted to document the reproduction steps that led to the aforementioned error.

Answer (score 0):

Like others have posted, this is resolved by cleaning the build folder or setting `CODE_SIGN_ALLOW_ENTITLEMENTS_MODIFICATION` to `YES`.

However, after cleaning the build folder, one build will succeed but any subsequent ones will fail with the same entitlements error until you clean the build folder again. Obviously this isn't optimal since it adds ~2-3 minutes per build even for one line changes.

The second solution involving `CODE_SIGN_ALLOW_ENTITLEMENTS_MODIFICATION` does away with the entitlements error entirely but install on physical devices fails every other build until build folder is cleaned. Same outcome really.

Does anyone actually know why this is happening in the first place? I inspected my entitlements file before and after build.. Nothing is changing. Is this just an xcode bug that costs us all hours of our lives?

Answer (score 0):

If <kbd>Clean build folder...</kbd> doesn't work, try manually deleting all the untracked files in your repository. You can do this by doing a fresh `git clone` into a new folder, or doing `git clean -fxd` in your existing repo. But be warned this will DELETE ALL untracked files.